# The kernel $k(x,y)=\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$ is a solution of which equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-equations

> The kernel $$k(x,y)=\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}$$is a solution of
>
> (A) Heat equation
>
> (B) Wave equation
>
> (C) Laplace equation
>
> (D) Lagrange equation

Which are correct ?

I tried through satisfying the equation of heat, wave, Laplace , Lagrange equation but I can't find it..I have no idea how we find it.

Please help...

Comment: Can you show your calculations? The heat and wave equations usually have a time dependence. How does that correspond to your $k$? Also, what about the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Comment: I know that heat and wave equations are time dependence..So I took $y$ as $t$...I think it can't take...In fact I have no idea...

Comment: Then what about (C)? I think you should show what you get...

Comment: Yes..I can do (C)..But the other options??

Answer (score 0):

### HINT:

The function
$
k(x,y)=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}
$
is in fact a special case of [***Poisson kernel***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_upper_half-plane), which is used to solve Laplace equation. More specifically, $k(x,y)$ is the Poisson kernel defined on the *upper half plane*.

---

#### Appended:

Technically the term "heat equation" includes steady-state heat equation, which is the Laplace's equation. So if you choose to be picky you can say that the question is not posed correctly.